# SpriteKit Find Last created Node with name

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, sprite-kit

Im wondering how to find node with name which was recently created.

```
   [myWorld enumerateChildNodesWithName:name usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
     mysterious code
    }];
```

But this functions goes through all nodes with `var name`
I want to just do my code on recently created node.

I mean i have node with names:

```
nodeId1   -old
nodeId1   -old
nodeId1   -old
nodeId1   -newest already created
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just assign every node you add to the same ivar. By definition the ivar will reference the node that was added last.

Declare the ivar:

```
@implementation YourClass
{
    __weak CCNode* _lastAddedNode;
}
```

When adding a node:

```
[self addChild:someSprite];
_lastAddedNode = someSprite;
```

If you want to be able to access the node by name, you'd have to give it a unique name. But this isn't really necessary with the ivar approach.

Comment: Thanks, missed that way of do this.